# Google Cloud Function delete Firestore document

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I tested my javascript on local emulator. There are 2 actions, if Timestamp is over 7 days delete the document (this is working like a charm <3) but the else is he should check the "img" its a normal url if this return 404 then delete like on the first action, this is ONLY working on local emulator, when i deploy it to Cloud function its not working anymore and just says e.g "Function execution took 7957 ms, finished with status: 'ok'" BUT on local it works as expected.

```
exports.removeExpiredDocuments = functions.region('europe-west1').runWith({ memory: "256MB" }).pubsub.schedule("every 1 hours").onRun(async (context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const now = firestore.Timestamp.now();
    const ts = firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(now.toMillis() - 604800000); // 168 hours in milliseconds = 604800000

    const snaps = await db.collection("products").get();
    let promises = [];
    snaps.forEach((snap) => {
        // functions.logger.info("forEachSnap");
        if (snap.data().created_time < ts) {
            promises.push(snap.ref.delete());
            functions.logger.info('[Time] older than 7 Days ' + snap.data().name, { structuredData: true });
        } else {
            requesth(snap.data().img, function (error, response) {
                functions.logger.info('[img] error: ' + error, { structuredData: true });
                if (response.statusCode == 404) {
                    promises.push(snap.ref.delete());
                    functions.logger.info('[img] not found ' + snap.data().name, { structuredData: true });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
});
```

Working on local emulator (with same url as in firebase) and i expect that its working on cloud aswell

Comment: Perhaps the "cloud" deployment cant get the image. Check the browser console to see if image is accessible and any errors.

Comment: @GetSet thanks for the fast answer, already checked, when the img is there i get 200 and when the other img that he should delete is status code 404 in browser console aswell

Answer (score 0):

`firestore.Timestamp.now()` does not return a value that can be correctly compared to other Timestamps with < and > comparisons.  That means this line of code doesn't do what you think:

```
if (snap.data().created_time < ts)
```

If you want to compare two [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) objects with each other, you must take another approach.  One way is to convert them both to milliseconds with [toMillis()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#tomillis) and compare those integers with each other.  Or convert them to Date and compare them with the appropriate object method.

Comment: interesting because that is exactly working multiple time tested now (aswell in cloud), my problem is the URL check not the timestamp thing as i wrote the timestamp is really working and does it as expected

Thanks for the answer <3

Comment: And yes i can rewrite the timestamp thing but this does not fix the url thing :D

Comment: If you have a separate problem or issue, it should be in its own post.  Stack Overflow only really works well when there is one question per post.  Posts with multiple questions will get closed as "need focus".